# Run 64-bit browser when also 32 bit is available - selenium

Tags: selenium, browser

I'm trying to make my tests run on a 64 bit browser when 32 bit version of it is also enabled. I normally use *iexplore or *chrome or *firefox to run everything but I cannot differenciate between versions of same browser. I found out that I can specify a path after browser name like *iexplore c:\program files\ (...) \ iexplore.exe. And yes, the browser does start but it displays only a home page it is set on to and does nothing more (though it should and do it when only *browser_name is specified). How to run selenium on a specific browser when multiple versions are available?

// **Found anwser**
Use iexploreproxy. But then you are most likely to get some certificate errors.

Thank you!